# Where are the sockets saved in the kernel?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, linux-kernel, internals

I am having troubles finding answer to this question:

When the kernel receives a packet and processes it, how does it knows which sockets are available? I have seen that there is some kind of a socket queue, but I am trying to dive into the details.

Is there a queue for each type of family (SOCK_RAW, SOCK_DGRAM, etc) and the relevant protocol handler checks whether in its queue for the relevant sockets, or is there one united queue? Or maybe I am wrong and it happens in a completely different way...

Comment: There is a socket receiver buffer per socket.

Comment: There is no "socket queue". Sockets are organized in hashtables based on their type and state (listening, established connection, etc). Packets are the ones that are organized in queues, but that's a different story.